# How is that possible that these two pieces of code have the same memory usage?

Tags: c++, ide, taskmanager

First case:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const int iterations = 1'000'000;
    std::vector<const char *> c;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        c.push_back("qwertyuiopqwertyuiopqwertyuiopqwertyuiopqwertyuiop");
    }
}
```

Second case:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const int iterations = 1'000'000;
    std::vector<const char *> c;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        c.push_back("qwerty");
    }
}
```

In both cases the shown memory usage of the active process is about 11 MB.

The first thought was that the memory usage refers only to the pointers size, but then how should i know from outside how much memory does a certain software uses? ( Without expliciting calculating the size from inside the code)

Edit:
I thought that with `c.push_back("qwerty")` i was creating a new string every time. That was my objective. I managed to do it now by modifing the code in this way:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const int iterations = 1'000'000;
    std::vector<const char *> c;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            std::string* s = new std::string("sadadasd");
            c.push_back((*s).c_str());
    }
}
```

It looks awful but at least now the memory usage makes sense. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?( I mean without introducing std::string and using only const char*)

Comment: Yes, both programs create an `std::vector` with one million copies of exact the same pointer value.

Comment: Space occupied from operating systems view is likely to differ from what's actually occupied in your process local space.

Comment: @OP Why would you believe that the results should be different?  Your code is no different than if you had `std::vector<int>`, in the first program you filled the vector with a million `0`'s and in the second program, you filled in the vector with a million `1000000`.  Just because the number you are using to fill the vector is larger, it doesn't mean the memory usage goes up.  Both vectors are still vectors of `int`, no different than your vectors are both `const char *`.

Comment: Looks correct. Around 8 MB (Probably exactly 8 MB if large pages are used) of pointers, 1 MB of stack, 2+ MB of mostly empty space containing initial dynamic allocations, memory manager etc and your program image

Comment: I added details in the main question.

Comment: No if you want to be able to store unique strings then you will need to allocate memory for all of them. If you don't want to store duplicates you need another datastructure

Comment: Yes the purpose was having 1 million identycal but unique strings.

Comment: Right now your code is written to guarantee that you experience a million memory leaks, because every single one of those `std::string*`s you `new` is immediately lost, never to be `delete`d. It's hard to answer if there is a "more elegant way to achieve this" when we have no idea what "this" is. "Create a vector of `const char*` that all point to distinct but identical strings, no I can't just create a vector of `std::string`s" is idiosyncratic, to say the least.

Comment: Is there a more elegant way to achieve **what**?

Comment: *"Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?"* -- this is a different question than what was initially asked, so is off-topic for this question. I suggest moving it to a new post before someone decides to use this as an excuse to close this question as "needs more focus -- asks multiple questions at once". (The new post should also better describe your requirements, such as explaining why `std::vector` is acceptable but `std::string` is not.)

Comment: "This" is "Yes the purpose was having 1 million identycal but unique strings." written just above your comment. But its also written in the edit, when i said that i thought that "I thought that with c.push_back("qwerty") i was creating a new string every time. That was my objective. ". Also, i copypasted some code to show you what i needed to achieve.

Comment: For the fact that i changed the question, yes you are right. Im sorry

Comment: *I thought that with c.push_back("qwerty") i was creating a new string every time.*  If you were using a `vector<string>`, then that would be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer takes up (usually) 8 bytes.

In both cases you create a vector with a million identical pointers. So that's 8 million bytes for the vector data. Total memory usage depends on more things, like how much empty space is in the vector, and how much memory is used by the rest of the process.

Both programs only include one copy of the string. The extra 44 bytes are a drop in the bucket. The second program might not even use an extra 44 bytes, if they were unused padding bytes anyway - which is likely, since the OS can only allocate memory in 4096-byte chunks called pages.

Comment: I added details in the main question.